# Change the position of the graph legend using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is there any way to change the position of graph legend in JasperReports? It shows in the bottom of the graph. Is there any way to customize the legend location? (place it inside of the graph). I am using iReport.

thanks.

Comment: @asked I have exactly the same problem. Did you get any fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

You have in chart options Legend Position and there you can choose where you want the legend.

Comment: But it only has left, right, top and bottom. Suppose I want it at top right position. Can somebody tell how this can be done?